# Can I set a different tintColor for each view?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6, tintcolor

Using Swift I'm trying to find a way to have a tintColor different in various Views and Scenes. Actually I've just successfully changed the barTintColor of the whole App.

Is it possible to adjust in each view the tintColor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your views need to be declared first, and once they are, you can reference them and their `tintColor`'s individually like so:

```
view.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
customView1.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
customView2.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
customView3.tintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
```

The first, `view`, is the main view, and each of the others are your custom views.

Comment: I've tried various solution but I don't succeed to declare a View... how do you do that? Thanks!

Comment: Try @IBOutlet var customView1: UIView! and make sure to connect the IBOutlet to your view in the Interface Builder.